# Postgres gem not loaded on initial Rails 4 app deployment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, deployment, ubuntu-14.04

I got my Rails 4 app running on my local machine and on heroku at the moment. Now I tried to set up an ubutunu 14 server. For deployment I am using capistrano and the connection between my local machine and the server is already set. Currently I am trying to do the initial deploy with this command:

```
cap production deploy:initial
```

I get following error at a certain point:

```
Running ~/.rvm/bin/rvm default do bundle exec rake assets:precompile on MYIP
DEBUG Command: cd /home/deploy/apps/savoir/releases/20160209113448 && ( export RAILS_ENV="production" ; ~/.rvm/bin/rvm default do bundle exec rake assets:precompile )
DEBUG        rake aborted!
DEBUG        Gem::LoadError: Specified 'postgresql' for database adapter, but the gem is not loaded. Add `gem 'pg'` to your Gemfile (and ensure its version is at the minimum required by ActiveRecord).
```

My gemfile looks like this:

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.1.8'
# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
# gem 'sqlite3'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0.1'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .js.coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
# See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer',  platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
# bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0',          group: :doc

# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

# Use debugger
# gem 'debugger', group: [:development, :test]

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin]

gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.3.5.1'
gem 'autoprefixer-rails'
gem 'bootstrap-sass-extras'
gem 'bootstrap-daterangepicker-rails'
gem 'bootstrap-datepicker-rails'

gem 'simple_form'
gem 'nested_form'

gem 'ckeditor'
gem 'coffee-script-source', '1.8.0'
gem 'carrierwave', github:'carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave'
gem 'carrierwave-crop'
gem 'rmagick'
gem 'mini_magick'

gem 'momentjs-rails'
gem 'gon'

gem 'jquery-ui-rails'
gem 'jquery-fileupload-rails'
gem 'jquery-turbolinks'
gem 'jquery-validation-rails'

gem 'devise'

gem 'ransack'
gem 'will_paginate'

gem 'rails_12factor'
gem 'pg', '~> 0.18.3'   

gem 'geocoder'
gem 'gmaps4rails'
gem 'underscore-rails'

group :development do
    gem 'capistrano',         require: false
    gem 'capistrano-rvm',     require: false
    gem 'capistrano-rails',   require: false
    gem 'capistrano-bundler', require: false
    gem 'capistrano3-puma',   require: false
end

gem 'puma'
```

And my database.yml:

```
development:
  adapter: postgresql
  database: savoir_development
  pool: 5
  username: postgres
  password: root

test:
  adapter: postgresql
  database: savoir_test
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
  username: postgres
  password: root

production:
  adapter: postgresql
  database: deploy
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
  username: USER
  password: PASSWORD
```

So as far as I can see it, the gemfile and database.yml should be fine. Can anyone find the mistake(s) I made? I found a few other threads that worked this topic but they didn't help in my case.

Comment: You have sqlite3 and pg both in the gem file, I think you need to add the pg gem to production environment in the gemfile, gem 'pg', group: :production, and then for sqlite 3,  gem 'sqlite3', group: [:development, :test], or just remove sqlite3 altogether if you are not using it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The sqlite3 gem is commented out though.

Comment: it is in the gemlock file?

Comment: No, it's not in my gemlock.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found the solution.

Since I was using windows on my local machine, rails used this version of pg:

```
//Gemlock.lock
pg (0.18.4-x86-mingw32)
```

Changing it to

```
//Gemlock.lock
pg (0.18.4)
```

and pushing it to the git solved my problem.